# How do I split the integers from a string in py3

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on an Arduino set up that uses both an infrared sensor and a sonic distance sensor. Since I'm using both of these, the serial port data needs to have a discernible tag from both data sets, I'm using ' cm' for the sonic sensor data.

My issue is I can't figure out how to strip the ' cm' tag from the sonic sensor data:

```
    if ' cm' in  data:       #used to handle the output from the ultrasonic sensor

    sonicdata = [int(s) for s in s.split() if s.isdigit()] #remove text so we can turn it into an integer

    if 20<sonicdata <40:
        pyautogui.press('playpause')

    if sonicdata<19:
        pyautogui.press('nexttrack')
```

when I run this i get the error message "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'"
and I'm confused so please help thanks

So it's just that one part that gives me an error

How would one actually take the integer from the data here?

Comment: Sorry but where is `data` used? `if cm in data` but then the variable isn't used after that? Did you mean to use it with split() rather than using `s.split()`?

Comment: Wowow in your comprehension you're using twice the variable `s`

Comment: Moreover sonicdata is a list, so the following tests are not ok (a list can't be compared to integers)

Comment: And `20 < sonicdata < 40` should be written `20 < sonicdata and sonicata < 40`

Comment: sorry I have no idea what I'm doing thanks for the feedback guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that data is a string, you can simply replace all cm

```
str = str.replace("cm", "")
result = int(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the generic case, a regular expression with the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) function can help here:

```
integers = [int(i) for i in re.split(
                 '(\d+)', 'measures 40 cm by  20 cm by 10 cm')[1::2]]
```

Using the capturing parentheses around the splitter pattern, the splitter itself is also included in the resulting list:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(\d+)', 'measures 40 cm by  20 cm by 10 cm')
['measures ', '40', ' cm by  ', '20', ' cm by ', '10', ' cm']
```

at all the odd elements. These can be accessed with `[1::2]`:

```
>>> re.split('(\d+)', 'measures 40 cm by  20 cm by 10 cm')[1::2]
['40', '20', '10']
```

Finally, the actual strings need to be converted to integers, done in the list comprehension surrounding the expression:

```
>>> [int(i) for i in re.split('(?P<int>\d+)', 'measures 40 cm by  20 cm by 10 cm')[1::2]]
[40, 20, 10]
```